# max file size exceeded nginx php

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, upload

I have NGINX server with FASTCGI php-fpm 127.0.0.1:9000 which php.ini is under /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini

I increased upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in php.ini

The Fastcgi params is like this

```
fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize = 200M post_max_size=200M"
```

I even increased client_max_body_size in nginx.conf file.

but on every file upload even less than 1mb, i get max size exceed!
any ideas please

Comment: Have you modified the FcgidMaxRequestLen variable as recommended by this post: http://forum.ispsystem.com/en/showpost.php?s=491a54e065a6420661a7a6d95557b6ee&p=6611&postcount=2

Comment: I added that like this fastcgi_param  FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824 ;
but still i have errors! i also changed fastcgi_pass from 127.0.0.1:9000 into  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock; but still same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i found the solution.

The problem was about Fastcgi_param in nginx.conf file.

it was about a \n between two PHP_VALUE and the right expression is like this:

```
fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize = 200M \n post_max_size=200M"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check *client_max_body_size* in your http, server or location block in nginx config (or relevant vhost config).

You can set a new value for ex. 200MB:

```
client_max_body_size 200M;
```

Check also the Nginx documentation at http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size

Comment: I did that too. my problem is i cant upload any file even a 1 kilobyte one!

Comment: I also have these 
send_timeout 300s;
        client_body_buffer_size 128K;
        client_body_in_file_only clean;